# Can't use a .deb file on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, deb

I recently was interested in modding, and I needed to install unity. I did that, and I run the .deb file, it comes up to the 'install software' application, then it says 'can't install Unity. Not supported'. Don't know why. I was able to run this VERY same .deb file on my old OS (MX Linux) but can't now...

Please help,

Thanks,

Ring Games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to install via terminal? Maybe it will give your a better output to understand what is missing.

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name.deb>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the following ways to install a package through a terminal:

1. dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb.deb
```

2. APT

There are actually 2 ways to install deb files with APT.

```
sudo apt install ./deb.deb
```

OR

```
sudo apt install /path/to/deb.deb
```

Comment: I'd have mentioned `dpkg` requires all *depends* requirements to be installed before-hand, or at the same time (ie. using the same `dpkg` command). That's the benefit of `apt` in it'll handle *depends* requirements (if available in your sources).